# Vertical Centering a DIV within an unknown height DIV

Tags: html, css

I currently have this HTML:

```
<div id:root>
  <div id:contents>
    <h3>I am the one that need to be vertical centered.</h3>
    <p>Lorem300..............</p>
  </div>
  <img scr:"somewhere.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

And the current SASS:

```
img
  width: 100%
  height: inherit
```

The problem I want to solve is I want the 'root' DIV to have the exactly same size as the img. In this case the img width is set to 100%, which means it always take 100% width of the viewport. Is there a way that I can vertically center the 'contents' DIV to the 'root' DIV? Thank you very much. I spent the whole day and still nothing found. Even when I use:

```
#contents
  top: 50%
  transform: translateY(-50%)
```

The 'contents' div take the height of the body, not the 'root' div. :(

Is there a way that I can solve this? Thank you!

Comment: yes, with a [ghost element](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/299/centering/4072/ghost-element-technique-micha%c5%82-czernows-hack#t=201704020728339892128)

Comment: You were on the right lines with `#contents { top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)' }`. Just add `#contents { display:absolute }` and `#root { position:relative } `

Answer (score 0):

```css
.center_block{
   position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center_block">
  <div>
    <h3>I am the one that need to be vertical centered.</h3>
    <p>Lorem300..............</p>
  </div>
  <img scr="somewhere.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to help you center the `#contents`

Simply set `#root`with these properties

```
#root {
  position: relative; /* needed to position img absolutely with div */
  display: flex; /* make this element flexbox */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontally center children */
  align-items: center; /* vertically center children */
}
```

Then give `#contents` and `img` these properties

```
#contents {
  position: relative; /* needed to set z-index */
  z-index: 2; /* make #contents above img */
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aptgc85w/) for example. And you can read more about css flexbox from the link above.

Hope this helps,